# Do soft casters on rolling chars hurt hardwood floors?

Tags: flooring, hardwood

Or should I just get a floor mat? Obviously I'd rather have the soft casters, if they do the job, but if they don't it's not worth it. What should I do?

Comment: I forgot to thank you! Man. I do appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If they are the soft urethane ones like those that are used at roller skating rinks, should be fine.

Check out the [chart here](http://www.castercity.com/casters-for-wood-floors.htm) and note that for hardwood floors, the wheel type is a function of (your + chair's) weight.

**declaration:**  not affiliated, related, in hock to or friends with caster city

Comment: Great chart!  I got this bookmarked for the future.

Comment: Good answer - know that it is all about weight displacement.  If your chairs did not pressure your wood before using casters then they won't after - unless something on the caster is scratching the wood.  There are soft woods that will dent from high heels.